# Running a for loop with two List(s)/Collections. Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I just thought this might be a handy thing to have/know;

I have two separate lists in a class. Is there a quick way to run a For/Next loop through two lists, Rather that two seperate For's as would be required in this example?

IE:

```
Public Structure Location
    Public Name As String
    Public ID As Integer
    Public IsSub As Boolean
End Structure

Public Shared MainLocationList As List(Of Location)
Public Shared SubLocationsList As List(Of Location)

Public Shared Function Get_Location_By_ID(id As Integer) As Location

    For Each location As Location In MainLocationList And SubLocationsList
        If location.id = id then
            Return location
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

I realize that with a list I could search, but Im asking as to also be applicable to say two lists of two different types of controls, or a collection etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the two lists with **LINQ** and then iterate:

```
For Each location As Location In MainLocationList.Concat(SubLocationsList)
    If location.id = id then
        Return location
    End If
Next
```

This will sequentially loop through all the element in the first list and then in the second.

Another less verbose way to write this is:

```
return MainLocationList.Concat(SubLocationsList).FirstOrDefault(Function(location) location.id = id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this could work too:

```
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Do Until x > MainLocationList.Count - 1 Or x > SubLocationsList.Count - 1
        If MainLocationList(x) = id And SubLocationsList(x) = id Then Return MainLocationList(x)
        x += 1
    Loop
    Return Nothing 'None Found
```

It may need some tweaking since i don't know what your looking for exactly in each list, what it looks like to me according to your example is your looking for the same id in each list matching up ***(This example specifically will return the list item with the same id in the same index order for each list.)***, but this is just another example of how you would be able to check both lists in the same loop you can count up by an integer and use the integer to check each instance by index number in each list. Hope it comes of use to you.